# How to place an image below a link in a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a ListView where in one of the columns I display an image and a link, here's the code:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock FontSize="20">
              <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Uri}" RequestNavigate="Handler1">
                <Run Text="{Binding Title}" />
              </Hyperlink>
              </TextBlock>
              <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Margin="5" Height="150" />
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>


      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column2}">
        <GridViewColumn.Header>
          <GridViewColumnHeader>Column2</GridViewColumnHeader>
        </GridViewColumn.Header>
      </GridViewColumn>
```

In the 1st column it shows a link and image on the same line, next to each other. I want to to show the image below the link. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your StackPanel Orientation to Vertical. (There's what it is by default, so you omit it if you'd like.)

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock FontSize="20">
         <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Uri}" RequestNavigate="Handler1">
             <Run Text="{Binding Title}" />
         </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Margin="5" Height="150" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: it's working but not exactly, there's a big gap between the left  border and image now, although there's no margin or something.

Comment: You have your Image `Margin="5"`. Is that causing the gap?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Orientation` of the `StackPanel` to `Vertical`

Comment: it's working but not exactly, there's a big gap between the left  border and image now, although there's no margin or something.